# My HUD has completely disappeared! What happened to it?

Tags: overwatch

After picking my hero in the pre-game lobby, I typically Alt-Tab out of the game to browse the web for a short time until the match starts. This time, when I Alt-Tabbed back into the game, my HUD completely disappeared! I could still control my character but I could not see my health, ult charge, ammo reserves, aiming reticle, nothing! In hero select for the next round, I could not see any heroes to choose from, so I had to stay with the hero I picked from the last round.

When I restarted Overwatch, my HUD was back on.

Why did my HUD disappear? How can I get it back if this happens again?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So it turns out I "fat-fingered" a key combination on accident while trying to Alt-Tab. Overwatch (and apparently most other Blizzard games) have Toggle HUD hotkey which is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> by default. I probably hit that key combination on accident while switching programs.

This feature is nice if you're trying to capture a screenshot of a scenic vista, interesting landmark, or particularly gruesome death. However you can disable the hotkey by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and clicking Options > Controls > Toggle HUD and unbinding the hotkey for the command.

Comment: I would also add that GeForce Experience users trying to record their gameplay may have the same key bind set to open their overlay. This is the solution to that problem too.

Comment: For me the shortcut was set to **Alt + Z**