# How do I unbind a hotkey in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes while playing Overwatch, I find myself [accidentally disabling the in-game HUD](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/299470/181240) while in the middle of a battle.

I'd like to disable the hotkey for toggling the HUD, but I can't find an option to unbind hotkeys. Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> after clicking a hotkey just keeps its current keybind options.

**Is there a way to unbind a hotkey in Overwatch?**

[image: Setting hotkey in Overwatch]

Comment: I don't know how to unbind, but as a stopgap for now you could bind it to something hard to hit by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Right click any hotkey to unbind it.**

[image: Right click to unbind]
*<sub>In hindsight, I don't know how I didn't see this before asking...</sub>*